# Why does Android Studio Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 6 keep crashing with Local History is broken

Tags: android-studio

I have updated my android studio to this version recently

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 6
Build #AI-223.8214.52.2231.9615888, built on February 16, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

and every day it fails numerous time and requires an invalidate cache and restart to fix
due to this error message

is anyone else experiencing this issue?
how do i stop it, as its wasting my teams time having to restart android studio on a regular basis every day

[image]

Comment: Android Studio Giraffe is a preview version. It's not even Beta, it's a Canary version, so you will often find errors. You can report this problem from menu option Help -> Submit feedback.